# Why is React Router is causing web app to crash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

Link to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tavares-convert-to-hooks-flxdf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to see what I mean.

When you load up the app with the Router / Switch in place, the web app doesn't load at all. Blank white screen.

However, if you comment out the code below:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
     <Route
       exact
       path="/tavares"
       component={() => <Tavares data={data.tavares} />}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/matthews"
        component={() => <Matthews data={data.matthews} />}
      />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/marner"
      component={() => <Marner data={data.marner} />}
    />
</Switch>
```

The app loads up again.

I'm fetching data of three players from the NHL API, and that code above is passing the data into other components. I'm not sure if this is causing some sort of lag or what.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Row, Col, Card } from "reactstrap";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import Intro from "./components/Intro";
import Tavares from "./components/Tavares";
import Matthews from "./components/Matthews";
import Marner from "./components/Marner";

import TavaresImg from "./img/tavares.jpg";
import MatthewsImg from "./img/matthews.jpg";
import MarnerImg from "./img/marner.jpg";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  // Set initial state for data
  const [data, setData] = useState({ tavares: [], matthews: [], marner: [] });

  // Fetch data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // Grab all players API's
      let tavares =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8475166?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      let matthews =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8479318?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      let marner =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8478483?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      // Axios to get all api's
      axios
        .all([axios.get(tavares), axios.get(matthews), axios.get(marner)])
        .then(
          axios.spread((tavares, matthews, marner) => {
            setData({
              tavares: [tavares.data.people[0]],
              matthews: [matthews.data.people[0]],
              marner: [marner.data.people[0]]
            });
          })
        );
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Intro
          main="Maple Leafs API"
          text="Built with React, React Hooks, Styled Components and Axios
                consuming the NHL's REST API."
        />
        <Flex>
          <Container>
            <RowWrap>
              <Row>
                <Col lg="4">
                  <Image>
                    <img src={TavaresImg} alt="Tavares" />
                  </Image>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="8">
                  <CardBody>
                    {data.tavares.map(item => (
                      <>
                        <Title>
                          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
                        </Title>
                        <Number>{item.primaryNumber}</Number>
                        <p>{item.primaryPosition.name}</p>
                      </>
                    ))}
                    <ButtonLink>
                      <Link to="/tavares">
                        <button>View Profile</button>
                      </Link>
                    </ButtonLink>
                  </CardBody>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </RowWrap>
            <RowWrap>
              <Row>
                <Col lg="4">
                  <Image>
                    <img src={MatthewsImg} alt="Matthews" />
                  </Image>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="8">
                  <CardBody>
                    {data.matthews.map(item => (
                      <>
                        <Title>
                          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
                        </Title>
                        <Number>{item.primaryNumber}</Number>
                        <p>{item.primaryPosition.name}</p>
                      </>
                    ))}
                    <ButtonLink>
                      <Link to="/matthews">
                        <button>View Profile</button>
                      </Link>
                    </ButtonLink>
                  </CardBody>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </RowWrap>
            <RowWrap>
              <Row>
                <Col lg="4">
                  <Image>
                    <img src={MarnerImg} alt="Marner" />
                  </Image>
                </Col>
                <Col lg="8">
                  <CardBody>
                    {data.marner.map(item => (
                      <>
                        <Title>
                          <h1>{item.fullName}</h1>
                        </Title>
                        <Number>{item.primaryNumber}</Number>
                        <p>{item.primaryPosition.name}</p>
                      </>
                    ))}
                    <ButtonLink>
                      <Link to="/marner">
                        <button>View Profile</button>
                      </Link>
                    </ButtonLink>
                  </CardBody>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </RowWrap>
          </Container>
        </Flex>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="12">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/tavares"
                  component={() => <Tavares data={data.tavares} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/matthews"
                  component={() => <Matthews data={data.matthews} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/marner"
                  component={() => <Marner data={data.marner} />}
                />
              </Switch>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

// Styles

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body,html {
    background: #eaeaea;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
`;

const Flex = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const Image = styled.div`
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #396afc;
`;

const Number = styled.h3`
  font-size: 30px;
`;

const RowWrap = styled.div`
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-4,
    .col-lg-8 {
      padding: 0px;
    }
  }
`;

const CardBody = styled.div`
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    margin-top: 60px !important;
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
`;

const ButtonLink = styled.div`
  button {
    width: 100%;
    background: #396afc;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    &:hover {
      background: #2846f7;
    }
  }
`;

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `App` tries to render itself if the path is `/`. Probably a good bet this is your issue.

If you consider what the effect of this would be without breaking it makes sense. It would infinitely render itself as a child.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian! That was it!